# Memused (calculate – Memtotal - Memfree ) from proc filesystem

Tags: linux, bash, proc

I tried to figure this out on my own but for some reason i can not figure this out can you please help me fix this. I am using the proc filesystem to parse information and redirect to a file. I just cannot get the memused.

```
mhz=$(cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep -m 1 "cpu MHz" | cut -d' ' -f 3-)
model=$(cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep -m 1 "model name" | cut -d' ' -f 4-)
memory=$(cat /proc/meminfo | grep MemTotal | cut -d' ' -f 2-)
free=$(cat /proc/meminfo | grep MemFree | cut -d' ' -f 2-)
version=$(cat /proc/version | cut -d' ' -f 3)
echo >> /home/user/data/proc 
echo Filename, field name, data >> /home/user/data/proc
echo /proc/cpuinfo, cpu MHz: $model >> /home/user/data/proc
echo /proc/cpuinfo, Model Name: $mhz >> /home/user/data/proc
echo /proc/meminfo, Total Memory: $memory >> /home/user/data/proc
echo /proc/meminfo, Free Memory: $free >> /home/user/data/proc
echo /proc/version, Linux Version: $version >> /home/user/data/proc
```

Comment: i was thinking i would just create a variable memused = $memory - $free

Comment: then i would return the value by echoing it out

Comment: I would cut out the numbers and do a subtraction in Bash, and at last append the unit.

Comment: not sure what you mean

Comment: `((memused = memory - free))`?

Answer (score 0):

This is meant to be a comment, but I don't have multiline in a comment, so here it goes:

```
mem_total_without_unit=$(</proc/meminfo grep MemTotal | grep -Eo '[0-9]+')
mem_free_without_unit=$(</proc/meminfo grep MemFree | grep -Eo '[0-9]+')
# print the free memory
# customize the unit based on the format of your /proc/meminfo
echo "$((mem_total_without_unit - mem_free_without_unit)) kB"
```

Example output:

```
12427860 kB
```

Comment: so i can just take the variable and instead of making a new var, i can just echo out total - free?

Comment: why is wrapped in (())

Comment: @johndoe Your variable contains units, so you can't do arithmetic with them. `(( ))` is [arithmetic expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Arithmetic-Expansion).

Comment: What you can do is use my `mem_total_without_unit` and `mem_free_without_unit` in the first place to replace your `$memory` and `$free` and manually attach units.

Comment: i apprecaite it ill give it a try

Comment: @johndoe Please feel free to come back with questions, or accept the answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The answer you get will be meaningless.  Ideally, Linux will utilize *all* you r RAM.  Caching I/O buffers and text in memory is going to invalidate your calculation.

Now, if the question you are trying to answer is "is my system fully-loaded", a more useful tool is vmstat(8):

```
$ vmstat
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ----cpu----
r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa
0  0 1131424 3734228 263588 3188088    1    1    52    91    6    6 41  9 49  1
```

What you need to watch is the SI (swap-in) column. If you see constant non-zero values, you are having paging issues.  The SO (swap-out) value can be ignored.

But, in general, if you are having paging issues, performance will drop like a rock off a cliff.

The web site http://www.linuxatemyram.com/ gives a light-hearted explanation of the kernel's memory management.